# How to retrieve the stripe customer id from the stripe object after creation of the customer

Tags: php, stripe-payments

[image]

```
<?php
require_once('Stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
Stripe::setApiKey(trim($pkey));

try
{
  $customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
    'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail'],
    'source'  => $_POST['stripeToken'],
    'plan' => trim($plan)
  ));

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  //header('Location:oops.html');
  error_log("unable to sign up customer:" . $_POST['stripeEmail'].
    ", error:" . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

here i want to get the customer id so i print the $customer object it  gives the stripe object but i don't know how to retrieve the customer id from that result.
If any one knows please help me.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the following line of code you will get the customer id.

```
 $customer = $stripe->customers()->create([
       'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail'],
       'source'  => $_POST['stripeToken'],
       'plan' => trim($plan)
    ]);

echo $customer['id'];
```

This will help you.

Comment: Thanks for responding i tried $customer->id  it works for me

Comment: @ravikumar please accept my answer. it really encourage others for their contribution. Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the customer object to get the id

```
$customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
    'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail'],
    'source'  => $_POST['stripeToken'],
    'plan' => trim($plan)
));

echo $customer->id;
```